# Is it possible to add special URL syntaxes?

Tags: feature-request

It's possible to create links to tag wikis using the syntax `[tag:graphics]` in a question or answer.

Is it possible to extend this mechanism, say to have something like `[docs:Plot]` turn into [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html)?

Comment: Very good question.

Comment: Related request on MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117372/documentation-links-in-markdown

Comment: @AnnaLear The difference here is that since we have a single system, it's very easy to figure out how to get from a documentation "URL" to a web URL.  What Brett didn't spell out is that the documentation centre of Mathematica has its own "URL" format.  For `Plot` it is `ref/Plot`.  To make this into a web URL, all one needs is to surround it with `http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/` **`ref/Plot`** `.html`.

Comment: @AnnaLear For built-in functions the address is *always* of the for `ref/FunctionName`, and there are no addresses without a `/` in them, so when the system sees `docs:FunctionName`, it would be clear that it needs to be changed to `ref/FunctionName`.  I too have been wishing for an easier way to get doc URLs myself, it's always a pain to go through the same copy doc url procedure again and again

Comment: Actually I was wrong, sometimes the address is a single word yet it's not a function (e.g. `JLink`)

Answer (score 5):

### Update

Please see

[**Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor**](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/187)

---

A first step would be to use and adjust this here: [Editor buttons for injecting documentation links](https://stackapps.com/q/2234/14269).

I would hack it, but I cannot get running under Chrome. Anyway, it looks promising to at least simplify for now

[image]