# Link Shortcut to Documentation

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to add special URL syntaxes?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259/is-it-possible-to-add-special-url-syntaxes)

This was brought up a long time ago in chat, but would it be possible to set up a link shortcut to the *Mathematica* documentation?  For example, we could have something like

```
[doc:Part]
```

which would generate

```
[`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)
```

with a possible alternative form

```
[some text](doc:Part)
```

which generates

```
[some text](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)
```

This would ease some of the work required in generating links to the documentation, and make making comments easier, too.

Comment: I'll poke the devs on this and see what's up. It'll have to wait for a while though, because they're all underwater in NYC and are currently operating out of their backup center. It'll only be brushed aside right now.

Comment: I had thought it was a conversation in chat. Oh well. Yep, the developers and their servers are a little water logged at this point.