# Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor

Tags: discussion, site-tools

Do you hate the guys trying to optimize every single part of a process? I'm one of those. Believe me, it's even harder for me. When I sit next to someone watching him writing something, taking the hand off the keyboard to mark a portion of text with the mouse, make a right-click just to *copy&paste*... I could explode.

Although, I'm quite fast with our SE editor, there are some things which could be further optimized. One big first step was the [Image Uploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/187). But there is another thing I always liked to have. A fast way to insert links to the online documentation of Wolfram. If you look at the URL style of e.g.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html

you see, that `Plot` can be exchanged with most other *Mathematica* functions and it works, because most of them have a *reference* page. Now wouldn't it be awesome if we had an additional button on the editor toolbar which when clicked transforms the marked text PlotStyle into [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotStyle.html)? This won't work for *all* functions but I'm sure, it helps quite a lot.

Another thing is, I'm the `theta` kind of guy. While I can at least *live* with the `θ` guys, I absolutely hate the `\[Theta]` ones. I think everyone agrees that the last option is the least readable. If there would be another editor button which just replaces the `FullForm` greek characters of a marked text, I'm sure this would be used very much and would help the readability of the code on our site.

**Question:** Is there a way to extend the editor on our main site?

Comment: `\[FullyAgree]`

Comment: I honestly think I thought of both of these things independently (who knows) but I lacked the ability or motivation to get this done.  Thank you, thank you!  Now if we can just get SE to include these in the interface itself.  (I've asked, but didn't get far with it.)

Comment: The `Ref`button could be useful also in comments

Comment: Related: [MathJax buttons/hotkeys script](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/389/mathjax-buttons-hotkeys-script).

Comment: Given that the ASCII character → (&rarr;) does exist, is it feasible to also replace the ugly `->`s?

Comment: Upgraded to Firefox 31.0 and it stopped working. Perhaps the new "mandatory" `@Grant` ?

Comment: **Firefox users (WinX)**. I've had a problem with the script not working anymore after upgrading to FFv30. Problem solved by re-enabling the FF error console (now disabled by default). Go to `about:config` and set `devtools.errorconsole.enabled` to True

Comment: I recently updated my installation of this script and the buttons no longer appeared.  I also got a new notice that the page was trying to load something from `jquery-utils.googlecode.com`.  Is this a new dependency and is it intentional?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, this dependency has always been there since the first version. Maybe your browser got more paranoid because I never saw such a message.

Comment: It is pretty paranoid since I run NoScript but it's odd this manifested only after the update.  It seems the script is loading `https://jquery-utils.googlecode.com/svn-history/r307/trunk/src/jquery.livequery.js`.  Not that it matters but can that resource be loaded locally (downloaded)?  I still haven't bothered to learn "hello world" in JavaScript.

Comment: Two small suggestions/request: 1._ When creating a reference link, remove any white space ant the end of the selection. 2._ Allowing the option of using ">     " for formatted outputs instead of `(*  *)` comments. Not sure about this one, bu what about also remove `Subscript`?

Comment: @rhermans Your first wish is implemented. If you have Chrome, you should be able to update the script when you have installed it through the official [chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb). If you installed it on a different browser, please find the changes on [GitHub](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons)

Comment: @rhermans Regarding your second point, there are two types of people here. The first type (like me) have a strong opinion that markdown quoting (>) should not be misused the fake an output box. We already have a [feature request](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/markdown-for-output) whether it would be possible the get our own output-style. I don't think this is going to happen and I would like to keep the used output styles as consistent as possible. So user of my original toolbar will be forced to the comment style output. Feel free to change my implementation.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

**Quick installation for the impatient.**  Choose your browser below:

- Chrome or Vivaldi – Install from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb).
- Firefox – Install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), then click here: [m_toolbar.user.js](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js)
- Safari – Install [NinjaKit](http://preston.kbs.msu.edu/NinjaKit.safariextz), reload the page, then click here: [m_toolbar.user.js](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js).  Extra instructions for MacOS 10.14 below.

Detailed instructions for any browser are below.

---

I hereby proudly present a browser user-script (userscript) which adds the required functionality to the editor of mathematica.stackexchange.com. This script is the *slightly* changed version of the [Ask Ubuntu Toolbar Buttons](https://stackapps.com/q/2405/14269) which only exists due to the incredible work of [Nathan Osman](https://stackapps.com/users/18/nathan-osman).

> [image]

Additionally, I added a button which is maybe rarely used, but *when* it is used, it saves a lot of tedious html-tag typing. With it you can insert *shortcuts* easily. Just click the button and insert the short-keys separated by space. Therefore, when you type `Ctrl C` in the dialog you get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

> [image: animation]

## Installation

### Chrome

Chrome users can download this extension directly in the [Google Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb).

Additionally, the script can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons) where you can have a look at the code or download it. To install it, please use this direct link to

- [m_toolbar.user.js](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js)

and install it into your browser. I have tested the script in Linux and Mac OSX.

In Chrome you install it by storing the file `m_toolbar.user.js` locally onto your hard-drive. Then you go in Chrome to Menu->Tools->Extensions and drag&drop the file there. After a reload of the SE page, the buttons should appear.

### Safari

In Safari (I tried OSX 10.6 and 10.8) one easy way is to use [NinjaKit](https://github.com/os0x/NinjaKit), which is an extension that lets you install user scripts.

First, download [the file NinjaKit.safariextz](http://preston.kbs.msu.edu/NinjaKit.safariextz) and install it by double-click.
After that you should see a ninja-star-like button in Safari

> [image: safari1]

where you can manage your user scripts.

**Safari 13:** The following workaround using "Extension Builder" [does not work anymore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370551/show-extension-builder-absent-in-develop-menu-in-safari-13).

**MacOS 10.14:** Extensions such as NinjaKit are depreciated as of MacOS 10.14.  Use the workaround detailed [here](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/) to get around this problem.  You may need to re-enable NinjaKit every time you restart Safari using the Safari menu Develop > Show Extension Builder.

Second, click on the link to [m_toolbar.user.js](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js). You should see a pop-up like this

> [image: popup]

A click on *Install* finishes everything up. Another click on the ninja star button shows you now the installed Mathematica script

> [image: scripts]

If clicking on the above link to `m_toolbar.user.js` doesn't work, try the following:

1. Download m_toolbar.user.js](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js) as a text file.
2. Click the NinjaKit button then NinjaKit's "Add new script" button.
3. Copy the downloaded `m_toolbar.user.js`and paste it into the "Add new script" window, overwriting the skeleton script that's already there.
4. Click the Save button at the very bottom of the window. (The name of the script embedded in the copied `.js` will automatically be used for the name.)

### Other browsers

For other browsers please read the existing [article on stackapps](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) about how to install user scripts.

## Update:

#### 8. July 2013

- Issue concerning *Canceled* dialog-boxes and empty input fixed
- Updated tool-tips for a better English. Thanks to [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) for the help.

---

#### 23. October 2013

- The dependent `jquery.livequery.js` is now loaded from googlecode
- Introduced another button for the stripping of `In[3]:=` and `Out[3]=` marks. For this you have to select the complete codeblock where the `I` of `In` is the first letter in the selection. Pressing the button removes the marks and comments out the output.
- Added `\[Element]` to the list of replaced glyphs
- Buttons-style is now more consistent with the webpage.

---

#### 27. October 2013

- [ssch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch) was so nice to extend the list of unicode characters by all characters of the [Listing of Named Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html) which have a unicode representation.

---

#### 28. October 2013

- ssch extended the `In[]`/`Out[]` cell label remover to work with several in- and outputs. Additionally, it can handle all kinds of *Forms* (like `FullForm` or `Short`)
- I moved the code into an official repository which is linked under the section *Installation* above.

#### 21. April 2015

- The Toolbar can now officially be downloaded in the [Google Chrome Webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb)

Comment: Using Safari on OS X, clicking on the link given in the  installation section referred to in the 28 October update notice, I only get a listing of the script. No popup menu. What should I do?

Comment: @m_goldberg You have to use the direct link which is given as bullet point. Try this here: [direct link](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons/raw/master/src/m_toolbar.user.js)

Comment: I did use the direct link. Problem turned out to be that I had _Block pop-up windows_ checked in Safari > Preferences > Security.

Comment: This is so cool!.. We should have an advertise for that! I discovered just now.

Comment: Fantastic add-on but I'm having problems getting it to work. (Windows 7 64 bit) Tried Firefox (via Greasemonkey) 1st & then Chrome. Symptoms: buttons don't appear. Using InspectElement it looks as though the script is running (I can see injected elements). I found that if I removed "position: absolute;" from .wmd-button the buttons did appear. (NB greasemonkey also says something about @grant not being specified). I have lots of greek chars in my code and don't want to abuse mod format assistance. Don't know why I can't run it like others :(

Comment: My last edit is just a keyword: I can never find this by searching for "userscript".  Now it will be possible.

Comment: Any plans on getting this into chrome store - as of today, it is disabled and cannot be re-enabled, nor can the drag-crx trick be used since it's not a package. I'd rather not switch from Chrome, or have to use a developer version of Chrome to use this very useful browser add-on...

Comment: How that the Programming Cloud is launched and v10 is imminent, can you switch over the Ref button to use `http://reference.wolfram.com/language/` as the base URL?

Comment: It doesn't work over HTTPS, but that should be an easy fix. I'll post an issue on Github as well.

Comment: @TeakeNutma I'll fix this. I already saw your issue on GitHub. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: The toolbar appears to be quite unstable in Chrome these days (I stalled in TamperMonkey following the advice in [this link](http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)), in most of the time it won't show up. Any solutions?

Comment: You should note the update to `/language/` in the update history.

Comment: I suggest adding `\[LeftCeiling] \[RightCeiling] \[LeftFloor] \[RightFloor]` to the conversion rules.  I find these generally useful.

Comment: Can I report a minor bug? The `Ref` function fails for message names. For example,`FindRoot::lstol` currently `Ref`s to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot::lstol.html, which returns a 404; instead, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/FindRoot/lstol.html would work fine. (On the other hand, not all error messages have documentation pages, so that's something to watch out for).

Comment: The installation instructions seem to be broken for newer versions of Chrome. I can get it through Tampermonkey but directly clicking on it fails and I get sent to [this page](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?p=crx_warning&hl=en&rd=1).

Comment: I seem to have lost the toolbar buttons.  I am using a Firefox derivative.  Is it peculiar to my configuration or are other Mozilla-family users experiencing this too?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I lost it as well and I'm using Chrome.  This is awful, now we are going to see a flood of unformatted Greek letters!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have fixed the script and a new version is available in the Chrome Store. I will push the changes to the GitHub repo in a second.

Comment: Thank you! -----

Comment: As a minor bug, this extension (both the userscript and the Chrome extension) gets broken by [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger). The relevant settings to fix this is to set `cdn.rawgit.com` to either Allow or Block Cookies. It would be nice to include this in the post but I understand if that's too much load on a third-party app ;-).

Comment: Every time I use the αβ button, the cursor jumps to the last line of the post.  This is annoying with long posts.  Can it be fixed?  I use Chrome on OS X. Do others have this problem too?

Comment: This is great (especially the glyph substitution). I could really use these buttons on other SEs than Mathematica though. Any chance you'll make that configurable in the Chrome version?

Comment: The direct link to install the NinjaKit extension for Safari seems broken.  I found an old copy I had and put it on my website at (http://preston.kbs.msu.edu/NinjaKit.safariextz).

Comment: I installed NinjaKit extension for Safari using Chris K's link. But exactly how do I add `m_toolbar.user.js` to the scripts? If I click the link to the latter shown above, it just displays the source of the `.js` rather than "adding it to the browser".

Comment: Never mind, figured it out (not at all obvious): Click the NinjaKit button, click the Scripts tab, click the "Add new script" button, copy the .js and paste it into the window, overwriting the skeleton script that's already there, and finally click the Save button at the very bottom of the page. What wasn't clear was to copy-paste rather than drop the file into the window, and that the Save button at the bottom was an action *on* the script, not an action to add *to* the script.

Comment: @murray Please don't hesitate to add this information under "Installation"!

Comment: The target of the link to the Safari NinjaKit extension given above (http://ss-o.net/safari/extension/NinjaKit.safariextz) is suspicious and possibly unsafe: it redirects to a site that asks for use of Flash Player.

Comment: This is the best thing happened to me today. thanks a lot @halirutan

Answer (score 8):

**Important note**: The Additional Editor Buttons Toolbar can directly be installed through the Chrome Webstore and the workaround below is not necessary any more:

- [Mathematica Editor-buttons for StackExchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb)

---

### Workaround for Windows users with the Chrome browser

A recent update to Chrome on Windows disables extensions which do not come from the Chrome Web Store, with no simple way to re-enable them. There are various workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24095006). I have used the "import the unpacked user-script in developer mode" solution, which is working fine though you do have to cancel a "disable developer scripts" dialog every time Chrome starts.

For simplicity here are specific instructions for halirutan's script:

- Create a new folder and move the **m_toolbar.user.js** file into it.
- Create a new file called **manifest.json** in the folder with the
  following contents:

.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "m_toolbar",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.mathematica.stackexchange.com/*"],
      "js": ["m_toolbar.user.js"]
    }
  ]   
}
```

- Open the extensions page in Chrome (menu-tools-extensions or navigate to chrome://extensions/).
- Check the "Developer mode" option at the top right.
- Click the "Load unpacked extension..." button and select the folder you created.

That should be it, after reloading mathematica.stackexchange the buttons will be back.

Answer (score 3):

Update extension from the author.

[Mathematica Editor-buttons for StackExchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added it now to my developer account as well and provided descriptions, screenshots and an icon. Find [it here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mathematica-editor-button/jelneigihibbkognjehbbembccihhbnb). Do you know what has to be done so that this can be found through the search in the Chrome Web Store? Is the rating important?

Comment: I installed the extension from google store but it does not provide the buttons, only the key button on the left. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @leosenko and what OS and Chrome version?

Comment: @m0nhawk  Chrome 42.0.2311.90 32 bit, on Windows 7 x64