# Installing Halirutan's script in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: support

I would like to install in Internet Explorer 11 the script described in [Meta 1043](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor), but am unable to find instructions for doing so.  (The article referenced in "For other browsers please read the existing [article on stackapps](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info) about how to install user scripts." does not address IE.)  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have a direct solution. It seems that *modern user scripts* can be run easily on each browser, except of IE. What I found is the [following discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876852/how-to-run-a-modern-userscript-on-internet-explorer) where someone asked the exact same question

> I've found it's pretty easy to take a Greasemonkey-type userscript and turn it into extensions/addons for Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. And of course one can run them natively in Chrome, and simply in Firefox using the Greasemonkey addon. I'm now exploring whether I can run my userscript on IE at all....

The answers in this discussion refer to two things:

- http://kangoextensions.com/
- https://crossrider.com/developers

Both frameworks seem to target what you have in mind, but I don't know any of them. Since I'm not using IE, even in the few minutes every year that I spend on Windows, I cannot be of further help.