# Help with formatting posts

Tags: discussion, formatting

I noticed that sometimes someone is editing my posts with better formatting.  I would like to learn how to do certain things so that others can save time not editing my posts. Are there instructions or a protocol on how to do things?

For example how can I make shift and tab buttons appear like this in my posts?

[image]

Comment: You can use the edit button to see the current formating of your post.

Answer (score 10):

See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help).