# A few links made with the Ref button from halirutan's button plug-in no longer valid

Tags: discussion

Wolfram seems to be reorganizing its on-line documentation and thereby breaking some links from this site. I learned this today when Saturisk left a comment to one of my answers saying a [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/49293/3066) I'd made to a documentation page was broken. It turned out to be easy to repair, but I worry that this may be the tip of a broken-link iceberg; that Wolfram may be reorganizing all of its on-line documentation causing many links on site to soon break if they haven't already.

The old link was http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/JSON.html
The new link is http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html

The change needed to restore the link was substituting *language/ref/format* for *mathematica/ref*.

The old link was made using the *Ref* button from halirutan's button plug-in, so users of that plug-in should take note and fix their documentation links should they fail to work.

#### Update

I started checking some of links appearing in rm -rf's list. The all seem to work as is. It seems redirection is working for these links and only old links that need to put into the form

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/

are not being redirected. If this finding holds up, then the problem is nowhere as severe as I feared.

P.S. And it's not 'mathematica` that is causing the problem in the broken links -- it's the absence of 'format'. Even

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/JSON.html

gets redirected properly. I guess this is why it took so long before a broken link was discovered -- there are really not that many. I apologize for crying "Wolfram" :-)

Comment: Related: [(259)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/259/121)

Comment: Since the change here involves two things and in other situations only one (Mathematica->language) correcting existing links may be hard to automize. Nasty.

Comment: @mr.wizard Could we have a feature request or so to repair this? I mean, even if we could edit all q&a's to reflect the new links there are still a zillion links in comments that we can't change. We need help from the SE developers.

Comment: @Sjoerd I think we should see how this plays out a bit more before we involve the SE developers.  Can we compile a list of all of the broken links so that a pattern can be discerned?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Perhaps people could post any broken links they find as answers to this question?

Comment: Where did you get the old link from?  The V8 and V9 documentation centers both link to [mathematica/ref/format/JSON.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/JSON.html), which the WRI web site successfully redirects to [language/ref/format/JSON.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html).  V10 links directly to the new location.  Maybe some microrev of Mathematica had a broken link that has since been fixed?

Comment: @WReach. Read the last paragraph in my question post. It explains the source of the link.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed @WReach's comment and your reply... so the issue is really w/ the plugin and not with WRI, since they're redirecting. I understand the limitations of the plugin though, and why this is not possible without hardcoding some of the `/format/` logic into the plugin... This is probably lower priority than if it were a site-wide issue w/ WRI.

Comment: @rm-rf. I have edited the title to make what I hope is a clearer statement the problem

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to point out, that there is absolutely no intelligence in the ref-button! Although one cannot completely understand the whole code from this snippet, I guess it becomes clear anyway what it does

```
ReplaceMarkdown(
  'Mathematica Function (like Integrate, Plot, ..)',
  '[`#INPUT#`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/#INPUT#.html)',
  function(answer){ return answer.replace(/^`(.*)`$/g, "\$1" ); })
```

The function was never intended to work always but as a thing that helps very often. I [already pointed this out in my original post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/187):

> If you look at the URL style of e.g.
>
> `http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plot.html`
>
> you see, that Plot can be exchanged with **most** other Mathematica functions and it works, because **most** of them have a reference page. Now wouldn't it be awesome if we had an additional button on the editor toolbar which when clicked transforms the marked text PlotStyle into PlotStyle? This **won't** work for all functions but I'm sure, it helps quite a lot.

I know I don't have to defend this, but what I wanted to point out is that it was planned from the beginning, that you have to check every inserted reference when you use this button.

On the other hand, **if** WRI now starts to change some URLs, there is nothing we could have done in the first place. Changing a published API (or in this case documentation) for such a large software is one of the worst things you can do.

Finally, if the button is supposed to work correctly, then there is IMO no other way except hard-coding the valid URLs for all possible functions, options, import/export formats, etc.. which would be quite a large list.

Comment: When I first posted this question, I didn't know that WRI was redirecting the links, so I thought updating your plug-in would be necessary. Now that I know that redirection is taking place, I consider my post to be no more than an alert making people aware of a situation when the results produced by the `ref` button  require some further editing. I hope that is clear in the post as it currently stands. I am sorry about being an alarmist at first.

Comment: @m_goldberg No, it's absolutely OK. I just wanted to repeat at this place that the ref-button has absolutely no intelligence and that users need to check the links it's inserting.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a list](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/293059/reference-wolfram-com-in-questions-answers) of all questions and answers on the site that contain a link to http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica. The list is sorted by views, so that we can start fixing the most helpful/viewed ones first. There are about 3.5k posts that have the old URLs.

Comment: I think all those links are OK. see my update to the question. I'm sorry that I caused you to waste your time on compiling the list.

Comment: @rm - rf, out of curiosity how did you manage to find all the posts that reference this url ?

Comment: @faysou the query I wrote is in the link with all the urls