# Proper way to provide a link to the Mathematica documentation in a question?

Tags: support, new-users, questions, etiquette

I am a new user exploring the Mathematica Documentation.

If I had a question on a particular cell in the Documentation how would I link it to a question on this site?

From googling around I discovered that there is online documentation which I can link from: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html?q=Classify

The limitations of this is that one cannot link to individual cells.

[image]

What is the proper way of going about this?

Comment: Can you unaccept my answer so I can delete it?  Mr. Wizard has a good solution.

Comment: yes I will do that but dont delete it. I found it interesting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you click on the blue `In[1]:=` on the *web* documentation page you should get a pop-up containing the code for it, as well as a short URL that links to the source.

For your section I get http://wolfram.com/xid/0i1lib1d8-vcqdub which when followed redirects to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html#1273900033

Comment: neat! I see its just at the bottom in greyed out writing on the pop-up box itself :)

Comment: It does not work for me on Windows 7, neither for Matematica 9.0 nor 10.3. Any special Option settings, that may have disabled this in my installation?

Comment: ahh... nervermind... you have to click on it in the online help in the browswer, not in Mathematica's help system...

Comment: @Thomas Good point!  Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 4):

**Ignore this and see Mr. Wizard's answer instead.**

---

<del>I am not aware of any ways to link to subsection in the symbol documentation pages.</del>  You could refer to a subsection as

> [`Classify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) documentation page -> Options -> Feature Types -> In[3]

There is a userscript that automatically inserts the documentation page link for a given symbol, but it is only for your convenience.  It doesn't provide any features beyond inserting the same link you show in your question, it just does it more quickly than manual copy and paste.

- [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)

---

Some of the advanced documentation pages have several sections that can be linked to directly.  Example:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html#1594022712

To get the link, I went to the table of contents and copied it from there:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html

It could have been copied from the HTML source of the page as well (more conveniently using the web browser's Inspect feature), but this is a lot of trouble and I don't usually have the patience for it.  `1594022712` appears in the `id` property of an `<a>` element.

Standard symbol documentation pages don't have sections that can be linked to directly, as far as I know.