# Posting equations with subscripts and Greek symbols

Tags: discussion

How can I write this equation in a nice manner when posting on  *Mathematica*.SE?

```
Cos[Subscript[\[Beta], 0][t]] Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], 0][t]] ==
  Cos[Subscript[\[Beta], i][t]] Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], i][t]]
```

Comment: If you can at all avoid it, don't use `Subscript`s in your calculation. Not only does it improve readability, it also protects you from sneaky unintended behavior.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 {} button : sorry but I didn't see this button

Comment: No problem.  But since you're asking about formatting anyway, I thought I share my boilerplate advice to help folks discover the tools for making nice-looking posts.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and so where is this button {} ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant you didn't see it but now you do.  If find it "above the edit window" as I said before.  It's between the quote button and the image button.  (By edit window, I mean the textbox for entering and editing the text of posts; I see it if I click on the "edit" button below your question.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 ok of course, I believed that you were speaking in Mathematica. But, even if I use {}, I need to suppress subscript and symbols. {} doesn't make the transformation for me

Comment: But it transformed the text in the question into properly formatted code, instead of being formatted as a quotation, which is how it was originally formatted.  (It was a comment about formatting your question itself, not an answer to your question.)

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a compound expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [Downvalue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102/10397) to the oprator `Subscript` and not an Ownvalue to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94298/10397)

Comment: I am definitely in the minority on subscripts but I agree it is best to avoid when posting to Mathematica.SE -- unless the problem at hand specifically relates to subscripts. For subscript usage in general I recommend using the Notations package. Surprisingly, for what it is, Mathematica handling of subscripts has never come close to e.g. Mathcad or Maple, but the Notations package can get you a fair way as long as you stick within its limitations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
expr = Cos[Subscript[\[Beta], 0][t]] Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], 0][t]] ==
   Cos[Subscript[\[Beta], i][t]] Sin[Subscript[\[Alpha], i][t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr /. Subscript[a_, b_] -> a[b]

(* Out: Cos[\[Beta][0][t]] Sin[\[Alpha][0][t]] == Cos[\[Beta][i][t]] Sin[\[Alpha][i][t]]*)
```

You can then use http://steampiano.net/msc/ to get:

```
Cos[β[0][t]] Sin[α[0][t]] == Cos[β[i][t]] Sin[α[i][t]]
```

Comment: Nice,  but there are always corner cases `Subscript[b, Sequence @@ {a, u}] /. Subscript[a_, b_] -> a[b]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Agreed, this is a partial solution at best. I honestly don't think the effort it would take to make this approach more general would be worthwhile. It's much easier to fix the problem at the root by avoiding subscripts altogether :-)

Comment: Absolutely, completely, unconditionally agree

Comment: @MarcoB And how can I do when I have several levels of subscripts ? I have tried this when I have expressions with 2 or 3 levels but it doesn't work :
Map[ToString, 
 q3Pattes /. 
  Or[Subscript[a_, b_] -> a[b], Subscript[a_, b_, c_] -> a[b[c]]]]
Do you have ideas why ?

Comment: Perhaps `Subscript[a_, b_, c_] -> a[b, c]`? There won't be any perfect solution; the unfortunate truth is that a lot of hand-conversion may be needed.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that there is no easy way to do what you ask. The editor we use on *Mathematica*.SE website does not support entry and display of two-dimensional forms nor does it convert *Mathematica*'s special character notation to Unicode.

Some amelioration is possible, depending on your intent for posting the code.

- For special characters that have Unicode equivalents, install halirutan's plug-in into your web browser (see [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)) and use the αβ button that it adds to our editor to make the conversion.
- If the snippet you are pasting in represents *Mathematica* **output**, then you can insert a PNG image of the output into your post rather than pasting in text.
- If the snippet you are pasting represents **input** to *Mathematica*, then you might post the expression both as text and as a PNG image of the input. Do not post a PNG image without a text version.

As others have already mentioned there are good, solid, technical reasons for avoiding the use of `Subscript` expressions in Input cells (cells that get evaluated). I, myself, never use them in Input cells. Pretty formatting does not compensate sufficiently for the problems `Subscript` expressions can cause in evaluations.