# How to convert Greek symbols to readable ones when posting here? web site is gone

Tags: discussion, formatting

I've used to use http://steampiano.net/msc/ to convert tGreek Mathematica  symbols when pasting here so they are readable. Now it is gone. See [posting-equations-with-subscripts-and-greek-symbols](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1816/posting-equations-with-subscripts-and-greek-symbols/1817) for example.

Is there a different site to use now? How else to do this conversion now?

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. I did not know about this.  May be should close this in this case as duplicate? Unless you post this as answer, will accept it.

Comment: To be marked as a duplicate the original must be on MSE rather than on Meta.

Comment: I tried posting as an answer; however, the "trivial answer" was automatically converted to a comment. If you want to expand the answer, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. My be I should then just close it. Will do that later on (unless I see an answer posted.).

Comment: I think there would still be value in an alternative that works on my iPad. I do a lot of MMA.SE browsing on my tablet and I liked to use the steampiano page to quickly convert special character when not on my computer. I'm sad it's gone...

Comment: This isn't a full solution, but at least Mathematica has ways of "knowing" which characters are which: exporting the expression converts to unicode. `\[Beta] = 1; Export["testingunicode.txt", Unevaluated[\[Beta]], CharacterEncoding -> "Unicode"]` Is there maybe a way Mathematica can then read this file in some form (without replacing the characters) and get it into the clipboard?

Comment: i'm interested in trying to provide a solution, and I have something that works to some extent but isn't perfect yet...please keep the question open for a day or two longer :)

Comment: @thorimur oh sure. Will be happy to accept once you have an answer also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Additional useful buttons for our M.SE editor](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor)

Comment: I think it would be very valuable to have an answer to a broader scope of this question, including the tablet users, and also Wolfram Cloud users. Copying from the *Wolfram Cloud* front end you get things like `SuperscriptBox["x", "2"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This morning (August 1, 2022) I tried to access the SteamPiano special character converter at http://steampiano.net/msc/ by mistake, and I was delighted to find that it is back online!