# More buttons for Stack Exchange Android App

Tags: support

Would the possibility that the additional useful buttons for M.SE editor will be applied to the Android version or Chrome Mobile?

The link below shows what I am wanting to comment:

[M.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor/1044#1044)

[image]

Comment: Do you mean editing posts in the Android SE app, or in a mobile browser?

Comment: I know that there is the Android SE app, but it does not have buttons that are being presented on the link, as the broker of `\[theta]` for `θ`.

Comment: So, then, you want the plugin to work with your mobile browser?

Comment: Yes. This is being developed or I am out of date? I tried using the Chrome Mobile, but it didn't work. I could be wrong.

Comment: It would seem that [extensions are not supported on Chrome mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604417/browser-extension-support-in-google-chrome-on-mobile).   You might have luck using the javascript code through the [tampermonkey app](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/is-there-a-way-to-use-userscripts-greasemonkey-scripts-on-the-android-browser), but you'll have to experiment and see.  If you want advice from the developer extension, I would just ask in a comment to halirutan's post that you linked.

Comment: Ok. I will try to use the Tampermonkey App.