# how to input gray background and hyperlink?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I saw that people can input code with gray background and include hyperlinks in their answers and comment, for example, the answers from the following link give a good example

[How to remove redundant {} from a nested list of lists?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/how-to-remove-redundant-from-a-nested-list-of-lists)

where can I learn how to do that?

Comment: In the `Your Answer` box below click on the `?` for help then click on `Links`. Also see the [`Markdown help`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the "edit" or "improve this answer" link under the post (whichever you see) and take a look at the [Markdown](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) source.

It looks like

```
[`Something`](http://link)
```

There are many of these because they are easy to enter using [these tools](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/12).