# Posting Symbols in the questions

Tags: discussion

A simple question:

How can I make alpha to appear like alpha instead of `\[Alpha]` when I post my codes here?

Comment: Maybe https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor

Comment: Is Installing NinjaKit is the only way for Safari?!

Comment: If in Safari you can open a second tab for this page: http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html and scrape the appropriate Greek character from the Entity column on that page and paste it into your Stackexchange message then that might sidestep needing to install more stuff. Example: β σ

Comment: Based on Entity column I still have these: `&Alpha`  `&Beta` &Alpha &eta;

Comment: @Hossein If your question about NinjaKit is because the direct link to install it is broken: I found an old copy I had and put it on my website at  http://preston.kbs.msu.edu/NinjaKit.safariextz.

Comment: Still another possibility  is provided at question [1137](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1137/1063).