# How do you format front end typesetting here in stack exchange?

Tags: support

When copying Wolfram language commands from Notebook front end to stack exchange how do you format here? For example,

```
\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Eta] = 1\), \(\[Tau]\)]
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(\[Eta]\)], \(\[Eta]\)]\)
```

Should look like

[image]

At the very least how to do `\[...greeks...]`?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/58370).

Answer (score 2):

I copy and paste your expression into a notebook and it is like this,

[image]

Since this sum will evaluate, I wrap it in [`HoldForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) and then apply [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html),

[image]

I copy this expression and wrap it in `$$`, like this

```
$$\sum _{\eta =1}^{\tau } \frac{\lambda ^{\eta }}{\eta }$$
```

and on the main site, but not meta apparently, and it renders as

[image]

This lets me put a math expression in a stack exchange post.  But if I wanted to post usable code that is also readable, I could replace `TeXForm` with InputForm:

[image]

which, when copied and pasted here gives

```
HoldForm[Sum[\[Lambda]^\[Eta]/\[Eta], {\[Eta], 1, \[Tau]}]]
```

This is already an improvement, but if you want to go a step further in readability, you can use the plugin described [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/58370) (as pointed out by Rohit in comments), and get

```
HoldForm[Sum[λ^η/η, {η, 1, τ}]]
```

Comment: Personally I prefer Ctrl+Shift+I.

Comment: @xzczd. Do you mean in a Mathematica notebook or on our main site? And what does it accomplish? I am not familiar with this keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @m_goldberg In _Mathematica_ notebook. It accomplishes task similar to `InputForm@Hold@\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Eta] = 1\), \(\[Tau]\)]
\*FractionBox[
SuperscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(\[Eta]\)], \(\[Eta]\)]\)`, except that `Hold` is not needed. The following is a GIF shows its usage (I've just pressed Ctrl+Shift+I and Ctrl+Shift+N): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHeT4.gif This is mentioned in [tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html).

Comment: @xzczd. I understand now. It's a little different on the MacOS version of the front-end, where it's Cmd+Shift+I. I use it too, but I usually just right click and get it off the popup context menu.